# Cannot type in the first instance of an app

Tags: 16.04

I cannot type in Firefox, Terminal or File Manager's search bar when I open them, but I can if I open a new window or multiple windows without closing the first window. What can I do?

Edit 1: The problem still exists after updating Ubuntu by `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Edit 2: The problem only occurs when Ubuntu is installed by `acpi=off`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that you can fix the problem by running the command `sudo apt-get update` and rebooting your machine. If it still doesn't work, you could then try uninstalling the program(s) and reinstalling it/them. You could also check for keyboard drivers (even though Linux is Plug-and-Play), or if your computer is slow, because it could be some kind of lag. Also go to the update manager and install the 16.04LTS latest updates and reboot. If everything above still doesn't work, you could still try installing another version of Ubuntu (e.g. the previous LTS version) and testing everything making sure you do the things above.

Hope it helped,
Js